# If a fork is forked, is it still possible to get upstream changes from the root project?

Tags: git, github

I'm wanting to fork a github project that other's have forked and one of those forks have changes that I would like to include in my fork. I'm concerned with being able to get changes from the top project into my fork since I'm not going to fork it directly.

The changes from fork that I want to fork are a few simple line changes but I'd rather keep with best practices by not copying/pasting code changes from a fork and only forking from the original project.

Is it still possible to pull changes from the originating project and the fork that I forked from? If so, what how do I pull from upstream from the very top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, just add another remote and fetch from that

```
git remote add topupstream <url to the master repo>
git fetch topupstream
```

now you can examine what the top level repo has:

```
git branch -r | grep topupstream | xargs git log --graph --decorate
```